Multi Input CNN with 5 input stream
I want to train CNN with 5 inputs. these 5 inputs are images with different types.
how to configure Input pipeline with tensorflow dataset or ImageDatagenerator?
my model make decision based on five input image stream. all these images are in directories and splitted to train, validation and test.
my dataset structure is like:
├──images-type-01
|   ├──train
|   ├──test
|   ├──validation
├──images-type-02
|   ├──train
|   ├──test
|   ├──validation
├──images-type-03
|   ├──train
|   ├──test
|   ├──validation
|
├──images-type-04
|   ├──train
|   ├──test
|   ├──validation
|
├──images-type-05
|   ├──train
|   ├──test
|   ├──validation
here is my code:
class JoinedGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, input_gen1, input_gen2,input_gen3, input_gen4,input_gen5):
        self.gen1 = input_gen1
        self.gen2 = input_gen2
        self.gen3 = input_gen3
        self.gen4 = input_gen4
        self.gen5 = input_gen5
        

        assert len(input_gen1) == len(input_gen2) == len(input_gen3) == len(input_gen4) == len(input_gen5)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.gen1)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        x1 = self.gen1[i]
        x2 = self.gen2[i]
        x3 = self.gen3[i]
        x4 = self.gen4[i]
        x5 = self.gen5[i]
        
        class_names = ['real', 'attack']
        num_classes = len(class_names)

    # Create a dictionary to map class names to indices
        class_indices = {class_name: i for i, class_name in enumerate(class_names)}
        labels = [class_indices[os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file_path))] for file_path in self.gen1.filenames]
        one_hot_labels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=num_classes)
        return (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5),one_hot_labels

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.gen1.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen2.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen3.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen4.on_epoch_end()
        self.gen5.on_epoch_end()
        


rgb_datgen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=45,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split = .2)
cr_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=45,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split = .2)
cp_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=45,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split = .2)
depth_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=45,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split = .2)
lbp_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=45,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split = .2)


    # Create generators
rgb_generator = rgb_datgen.flow_from_directory(
        rgb_dir,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary' # If no labels, set class_mode to None
    )
cr_generator = cr_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        cr_dir,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary' # If no labels, set class_mode to None
    )
cp_generator = cp_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        cp_dir,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary' # If no labels, set class_mode to None
    )
depth_generator = depth_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        depth_dir,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary' # If no labels, set class_mode to None
    )
lbp_generator = lbp_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        lbp_dir,
        target_size=(128,128), # Adjust channels for RGB
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary',
    )


my_gen = JoinedGen(rgb_generator, cr_generator, cp_generator,depth_generator,lbp_generator)



but see this error when model.fit():
Layer "functional_7" expects 5 input(s), but it received 10 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'data:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_1:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_2:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_3:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_4:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_5:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_6:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_7:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_8:0' shape=(None, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'data_9:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>]


did you try using tf.data api (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to create a custom input pipeline or use the imagedatagenerator from Keras (https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) to handle the data..

I create custom ImageDataGenerator according to link but after model.fit() the model recognize 10 inputs insted.
